# Angular 2 + Openlayers 3, Loses the component reference when I add the function to an interaction

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers-3

I need to keep my component reference when I create a new interaction with a defined method in its properties. So an example:

In a DrawComponent.ts:

```
@Input() map:any;
layer:any;

// Filters functions
layerFilter(itemLayer:any) {
    console.log(this) 
    return (itemLayer === this.layer);
};

// Init select interaction
select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: this.layerFilter
});

// Add select interaction to the map
this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
```

the console log inside the layerFilter return NULL because I lose my component reference.

Do you have a solution or an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the arrow function to avoid the "this" context from being changed.

```
@Input() map:any;
layer:any;

// Filters functions
layerFilter = (itemLayer:any) => {
    console.log(this) 
    return (itemLayer === this.layer);
};

// Init select interaction
select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: this.layerFilter
});

// Add select interaction to the map
this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who will have the same problem, I found a solution but i don't know if it's a good pratice.

I bind the context of my component to my method with the function .bind()

```
// Init select interaction
select = new ol.interaction.Select({
     layers: this.layerFilter.bind(this);
});
```